Lcapy (python) gives wrong voltage if ammeter is connected
Here's the circuit:
cct = Circuit(
"""
  Vx 1 0 dc 12; down
  R1 1 2 20; right
  AM 2 4; down
  R2 4 0_4 30; down
  R3 2 3 40; right
  R4 3 0_3 20; down
  W1 0 0_4; right
  W2 0_4 0_3; right
"""
)


When I look for voltage around R2, it output as zero.
cct.R2.V // 0
cct[4].V // 0

From my understanding, it should not be zero. Am I doing something wrong or it's an issue with Lcapy?

I get 6 V across R2.

@PeterBennett Interesting, is it cct.R2.V value or some other way?

Calculate R3/R4 in parallel with R2 then that in series with R1 to form a voltage divider, then Ohm's Law to get the current.

Yes, 6V is correct but the main issue is that Lcapy is showing wrong result. I just wanted to confirm if the circuit described is correct and I'm not doing something wrong.

Seems broken to me. I'm not familiar with this program, so this is a comment, but replacing the AM with a 1mΩ resistor yields the symbolic answer 270000/45001 V on node 4, a bit under 6V, as expected. Replacing it with a 0Ω resistor yields a 'nan'. And the ammeter, as you say, 0.

Thanks for confirmation everyone. I have filed a bug report.
